# How to call method on presenting view controller from modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a modal view controller that I called in from another view controller. Upon dismissal of the modal view controller, I want a method to be called on the view controller that presented that modal view. What is the easiest way to do this?

I tried doing this in my modal view controller: `[(ParentViewController*)self.presentingViewController foo];` before calling `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`.

Xcode gives me an error saying foo isn't recognized, even though it is defined and prototyped in the controller. If your solution involves blocks, I really don't understand them so I would appreciate it if you would add more detail. Thanks.

ParentViewController.h

```
@interface ParentViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NewAssignmentViewController *newAssignmentViewController;
    TableViewDataSource *data;
}

-(void)foo;

@end
```

Comment: You get that error because the compiler doesn't know what class self.presentingViewController is. To fix it, just cast it: [(MyClass *)self.presentingViewController foo]

Comment: Please include the code you have in ParentViewController.h

Comment: I don't think the problem isn't the implementation of foo because the program crashes even if foo doesn't do anything

Comment: Put a log in just before you dismiss the modal view controller, NSLog(@"%@",[self.presentingViewController class]) and see what it returns

Comment: UITabBarController...

Comment: Ok, that's your problem. You never mentioned that these controllers were embedded in a tab bar controller. When you do a presentation from a controller in a tab bar controller, it's actually the tab bar controller that does the presentation, not the controller you called it from.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know that. So how can I fix my problem? The view is the first controller of the tab bar controller

Comment: Which tab is ParentViewController in?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35246/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-iowa15)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to get a correct reference to your presenting controller like this:

```
ParentViewController *presenter = [(UITabBarController *)self.presentingViewController viewControllers][0]; // 0 is assuming that ParentViewController is in the first tab. Change if necessary
[presenter foo];
```

The other way to do it would be to use delegation, but that's an answer for another time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Storyboard segue to present your view controller you could dismiss it using an Unwind Segue.  An unwind segue is a special kind of segue that unwinds the presented view controllers back to a presenter.

To accomplish this, you would create a method in the presenting view controller with the following signature:

```
- (IBAction)unwindAction:(UIStoryboardSegue*)unwindSegue;
```

This is different than a standard `IBAction` because the parameter type is a `UIStoryboardSegue*` instead of the normal `id` type (it doesn't have to be named `unwindSegue:`, it could be `modalViewFinished:` or whatever you like - the important part is that it has a return type of `IBAction` and a parameter type of `UIStoryboardSegue*`).

Once you have this method defined, in your storyboard you control-drag from the modal view controller icon (below its view, in the little bar of icons) and release the connection on the green exit sign.  This will create an unwind segue, which you should give an `identifier` in the attributes inspector.  Unwind segues will not show up visually in the storyboard canvas, so you will have to find it in the list of items on the left side of the canvas (this is collapsed by default, expand it by clicking the little circular button in the lower left hand corner of the canvas).

Once you've done that, rather than calling `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]`, just call `[self performSegue:<Identifier you gave the unwind segue>]` instead.  During this process the `unwindAction:` method defined on the presenting view controller and the `prepareForSegue:` method on the modal view controller should be invoked.  You can do whatever cleanup you need to do in these methods (calling the `foo` method from `unwindSegue:`, for example).

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using Storyboards

Comment: @Iowa15 Ah, too bad, exit segues are nice.

Comment: Yeah I'm just starting to learn iPhone programming, but I'll definitely use them next time

Comment: @CharlesA. I get `Attempt to dismiss from view controller <MyTabBarController: 0xc233600> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!` after `modalViewFinished:` is invoked. Modal view stays on the screen. What can I do ?

Comment: @ruslan It sounds kind of like still have code that is explicitly dismissing your view controller somewhere.  You'll need to remove that, the unwind segue does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You call the method on the UIViewController that is your MainView, and pass it your UIViewController you want to be the ActionSheet.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheetController =[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"show otherview", nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:actionSheetController animated:YES ];
```

To dismiss the UIActionSheet, dimissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated: is a method for the UIActionSheet that you can implement. The method can be called by whoever (so if you want to dismiss it from your mainview have a reference to the action sheet and do something like

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
{
        switch (buttonIndex){
            case 0:
            {
               [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
            }
                break;

            case 1:
            {
                MyClass *myclassObject = [[MyClass alloc]init]; 
                [myclassObject foo];
            }
       }
}
```

The method is also called whenever the 'cancel' button is clicked by the user.

Use this [ModalViewControllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) link for better understanding...!

Comment: Please let me know if any problem occurs.

Comment: I'm still not exactly clear on this. What I want to do is have my modal view controller call a method on the view controller which presented it

Comment: Use it by creating a reference of your self.presentingViewController class
MyClass *myclassObject = [[MyClass alloc]init];
[myclassObject foo];

Comment: Ok I get it. Let me try that

Comment: I get a warning which says: incompatible pointer types assigning to MyClass *__strong' from 'UIViewController*'

Comment: Using a cast makes the program crash

Comment: @Iowa15, using a cast, as I said in my comment will work. If you're getting a crash then you're doing something wrong. Update your question to show what you're trying now.

Comment: @Iowa15, if it crashes, you need to post what error you get. Saying "it crashes" is not useful.

Comment: @lowa15 please import MyClass and try to call foo method of MyClass

Comment: No problem calling it foo on MyClass. It only crashes when I call it on the presenting view controller